# How to async an ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I have a MVC 5 Web Application, Method `.Check()` is a long running process.

How to asynchronous use the ApiController ?

Could you point me out in the right direction?

```
public class ReportCheckController : ApiController 
{
    private ReportProcessStatusesBLL checkReportsBLL = new ReportProcessStatusesBLL();
    public void Get()
    {
        if (!checkReportsBLL.Check())
            helpers.BusinessLayer.CreateResponseApiMessage(checkReportsBLL.Errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the result of `Check` determines the response of the `Get` call I don't think making the call asynchronous is what you want here.

Comment: Why do you want it to be asynchronous?

Comment: Making the controller asynchronous won't help if `Check` blocks. `async\await` don't make code execute asynchronously by magic, they make waiting for the result of already asynchronous operations easier.

Comment: James +1. You can only do fire and forget if your response doesn't need/care the value of `checkReportsBLL.Check()`

Comment: I would suggest reading stephan clearys blog post about asynchronous work in ASP.NET: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html and http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html

Comment: of interesthttp://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Comment: http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc